# Can anyone explain this cryptic warning regarding socket_select()?

Tags: php, sockets

I have a question regarding a note in the PHP documentation regarding the use of `socket_select()`.

> **From [http://www.php.net/socket_select](http://www.php.net/socket_select#refsect1-function.socket-select-notes):**
>
> No socket resource must be added to any set if you do not intend to check its result after the socket_select() call, and respond appropriately. After socket_select() returns, all socket resources in all arrays must be checked. Any socket resource that is available for writing must be written to, and any socket resource available for reading must be read from.

I'm wondering what this means in practice, specifically in relation to reading.

- What will happen if you don't call `socket_recv()` for one of the returned sockets?  Will the socket be closed?  Fatal error?  Data loss?
- What if there is still data in the socket's buffer after your call to `socket_recv()`?  Do you need to make further calls until the buffer is empty?  Or the opposite - should you avoid calling `socket_recv()` until you have called `socket_select()` again?  Or does it not matter either way?

The comment is a bit cryptic - it gives a warning that something is bad without really being clear about how to avoid it or what the impact will be!

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that the sockets supplied in the input arrays will lock up until you clear their buffers, causing further interactions with the sockets later on to cause issues. Best approach would be to loop through each array, and in that loop, loop again on each socket until the socket no longer returns anything from its buffer, as examples show further on down the documentation page that you supplied